# The majority of regular posters here are Catholic which creates problems for Prot. posters

Tags: bug, moderation, moderators

Note: NB There are Catholics and Protestants on the site that this doesn't apply to, who do not seem to be doing the below-mentioned, and it may not be a Cath/Prot. issue, because some of the times I saw this it was a question Cath/Prot differ on, but there were times when a small group seemed to differ because it was doctrine they were not supportive of, then the question got held up.(or could it be it was something they hadn't heard before?) It's hard to tell some things from type,...I am probably not familiar enough with how this works to be saying anything - sorry if others can see this is so and I am making a nuisance of myself and giving people who have to make these decisions on questions a headache, but, if I'm right, please make adjustments.:)(im probably giving headaches, right, if so, sorry.)

The problem is if a Protestant posts a question that the Catholic posters don't agree with or have never heard of before, it seems it is often closed, or a few people comment, and it is discarded.

There is an additional issue just as important, in that if those reading your question are from another 'tradition' that does not favour the topic of your question (not the Cat/hprot divide) you may be downvoted because they don't like or agree with the doctrine that the question is about.

Additionally, I have seen downvotes on questions that were rude and biased and seemed to be done for no reason relating to the question. in the comments where these type of downvotes were done, the remarks were not kind or in keeping with the Christian love ethic.

Voting is very biased if most of those voting are Catholic on a Protestant question.

I matched 15/20 board names as the very same names used by same people (pictures/name signs)on a Catholic forum board.

Christianity SE is biased because of this and is not working properly.

I think questions are not dealt with fairly nor in keeping with the SE rules.

There also seems to be a group of posters who have been on this board for awhile together, and they vote each other's questions that seem no different to me than other's questions I see who are downvoted. In fact some questions downvoted seem better than the upvoted ones, and these I saw got -1, -2 downvotes, and the lesser questions sometimes got 10 or 6 upvotes, kind of like this 'group' were all 'online' together and upvoted each other, maybe because they knew each other?

Comment: Can you provide a few of the best examples of questions that you think were unfairly treated in this way?  (I'm not Catholic, and, based on my own general experiences here, I wouldn't agree with your assessment.)

Comment: Your assumption is just plain wrong - the majority of regular Posters are not Catholic. The downvotes on your posts relate to issues of quality not sectarianism. (I am happy to self-identify as a Protestant when I say this)

Comment: Definitely not true, most regulars are protestants from what I can tell.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a different issue and might be a real concern. New users do have a harder time earning upvotes. The community doesn't know them yet, so the content is scrutinized harder.

Comment: Well, I see plenty of [question tagged Protestantism](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protestantism) that look like they are doing just fine on the site.

Comment: I don't think many if any of my questions were Protestantism, yet this tag appears under my name under 'users'? Who put that tag there?

Comment: `Who put that tag there?`  This is another thing that you would benefit from figuring out for yourself.  As a hint, it's based on *both* questions and answers.

Answer (score 9):

> I am probably not familiar enough with how this works to be saying anything

Frankly, no, you aren't familiar enough with SE sites in general or this one in particular to be making this sort of judgement.

- As pointed out in comments, the majority of posters here are not Catholic.  There've been a fair number of Catholic questions recently, but that's just a normal variation over time.
- Downvotes are not "rude," nor are they supposed to be "friendly".  A downvote means someone thinks the post (Q or A) is not clear, or not useful.  Their purpose is to tell future visitors how the community ranks a post on a relative scale.  They also give some feedback to the person who made the post, but that's a secondary purpose.
- You say there's a bias but you offer no proof and in fact you can't - no one knows how other people vote (yes, I know, SE staff can find out) so you don't know who's downvoting posts you think don't deserve it.

> kind of like this 'group' were all 'online' together and upvoted each other, maybe because they knew each other?

- This last comment shows that you *really* don't know how SE works - voting rings are a huge no-no and are swiftly stamped out when they show up.  Some sort of cabal voting together is absolutely not why posts you think are good have been downvoted.

Comment: Because I am newer I am at a disadvantage, but I do read questions that are upvoted and compare them with mine, and from this I see some of mine have been wrongfully downvoted, when the question is pertinent, not duplicated and is of interest to a wide group within Christianity. I am not too new to notice this. Some downvotes are completely ridiculous. In the opening where people's names appear, I have a Protestantism tag under my name, who gives these tags and why are they there, because my questions have been right across the board, to include Cath. and Prot. and many other groups

Comment: `Because I am newer I am at a disadvantage` to some extent this is true, and the best way to overcome that disadvantage is to spend time figuring out how the site works.  This includes time spent reading posts here, on meta., on the site-wide meta, and on other sites.  It also includes time reading the SE blog, and *all* of the help/introduction pages.  People who have been on various SE sites for *years* have put in a lot of hours reading and understanding how things work.  You can't hope to duplicate that level of understanding in a short period of time.

Comment: ...In the meantime, it's not efficient for people to answer your flurries of questions as they occur to you.  e.g. ` I have a Protestantism tag under my name, who gives these tags and...`  It's not clear exactly what you mean, I assume you're talking about the list of tags on your profile summary page, and to answer that you need to read about what tags are, what they're meant to do.

Comment: The final thing I'll point out is that downvotes have nothing to do with whether a question is pertinent, a duplicate, or of interest to a wide group.  There is a clear, concise  definition of what downvotes mean, as a useful exercise for you, I'll leave it to you to find it.